# why is my github action failing after i refactored it to run jobs in parallel?

Tags: node.js, github-actions

I have a github action for a Next.js app that runs unit tests, typechecks and other normal stuff.

It was all one job before, which worked fine, but I've just refactored it to run in parallel (using the `needs:` syntax to specify dependencies), and now all the dependent jobs (other than setup) are failing right away with a basic npm error:

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/lbh-core-pathway-pilot/lbh-core-pathway-pilot/package.json'
```

[image]

the job config i'm using is:

```
name: CI
on: push
env:
  DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres"
  NEXT_PUBLIC_API_HOST: "http://localhost:3000"
  NEXTAUTH_URL: "http://localhost:3000"
  NODE_ENV: "test"
  PORT: "3000"

jobs:
  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up test database
        uses: harmon758/postgresql-action@v1
        with:
          postgresql version: "11"
          postgresql db: "postgres"
          postgresql user: "postgres"
          postgresql password: "postgres"

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm i

  type_check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: setup
    steps:
      - name: Check types
        run: npm run typecheck

  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: setup
    steps:
      - name: Run lint
        run: npm run lint

  unit_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: setup
    steps:
      - name: Run unit tests
        run: npm test

  integration_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: setup
    steps:
      - name: Apply database schema
        run: npm run db:push

      - name: Seed database
        run: npm run db:seed

      - name: Build app
        run: npm run build

      - name: Integration tests
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          start: npm start
          wait-on: http://localhost:3000/

      - name: Upload screenshots
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        if: failure()
        with:
          name: cypress-screenshots
          path: cypress/screenshots

      - name: Upload videos
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        if: failure()
        with:
          name: cypress-videos
          path: cypress/videos
```

I've checked [Github's documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds) for this and can't see any help.

Comment: someone elsewhere told me that filesystem state isn't preserved between jobs, causing this.

that makes sense i suppose, but i'm curious how to achieve what i want here (the time saving that comes from npm installing once and then running everything else in parallel)

Comment: Did you try assing the `actions/checkout@v2` step to the other jobs as well? (to access the package.json file when needed)

Comment: *Did you try **using**